# OAuth2: Error 401 Unauthorized at PHP request with access_token (Discord API)

Tags: php, oauth, oauth-2.0, discord

I'm currently trying to receive the user's Discord information over PHP after the user authorized the log-in via his Discord account. The authorization and authentification already work, so **the access_token is valid**.

Everytime I send the request, I receive a 401 Error, looking like this:

```
{"code": 0, "message": "401: Unauthorized"}
```

The PHP code is currently this one:

```
$second_curl = curl_init( 'https://discordapp.com/api/users/@me');  
curl_setopt( $second_curl,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); 
curl_setopt( $second_curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Authorization: BEARER ".$secret->access_token)); 
$me = curl_exec( $second_curl ); 
echo $me;
```

With $me echoing the mentioned error response.

I simply can't find the fix for it. Does anyone have a clue about the odd response from the OAuth2 server?

Answer (score 1):

I was unauthorized since I only used the email scope, but left out the identify scope. If you're having the same issue, make sure to use `scope=identify+email`!

Comment: I had the same problem. Your solution helped. Thank you very much.